# Eating non-kosher food then drinking out of kashered cup?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Does drinking a cold drink several minutes after eating cold non-kosher food render the cup non-kosher since it is making contact with the mouth, which may still have remnants of non-kosher food in it? Does the answer differ if the cup is glass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a not-hot kosher vessel came in contact with not-hot non-kosher food, the vessel should be very thoroughly washed with cold water and scrubbed to remove any remnant of the non-kosher food before resuming kosher use. ([Shulchan Arukh YD 121:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%90_%D7%90))

Comment: I am by disrupting your way to define the "off topic". I do not see why this is good while that of onion cut by a knife Chalavi is not.

Comment: @kouty I might be the guilty one here as I edited the question to make it less of a request for psak and more theoretical. I then realized (in chat) that this is best not done. Learning for me. On the  other side, I am now really interested in the answer on the other one with all the points you surfaced!

Comment: @mbloch
I am trying a plastic surgery on the question about onion but the initially Girsa disappear. please see the begining I wrote and paste the initial question bellow if you are technically able. Thanks ;)